# Is this the paradox of reaction forces?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, aerodynamics

[image]
As shown in the figure, a beaker has a straight, equal-diameter pipe at the bottom, and water flows out of the pipe outlet.  The red curve represents the pressure gradient.  It is generally believed that the exit section of the pipe (A-A) has a reaction force.  But according to theoretical analysis, along the flow direction, the pressure in the pipe is gradually reduced, and the pressure at the outlet section of the pipe is atmospheric pressure, so there is no reaction force at the outlet section.  This creates a paradox.  Some people say that energy is conserved and water has acceleration, so there must be a reaction force.  But I want to say that there is acceleration at the entrance of the tube, so there is a reaction force at the entrance of the tube, and there is no reaction force at the exit section of the tube (the pressure in the tube is the result of friction).  Just as we keep throwing stones into the pipe at the entrance of the pipe, the stone at the entrance of the pipe has acceleration, but the stone in the pipe has no acceleration.  So, how to explain this paradox?

Comment: What do you mean by "the exit section of the pipe has a reaction force."  I think that wording might be where the paradox is unfolding.  After all, if I replace your pipe outlet with a double tube somewhat like a trombone slide, it's easy to intuit that the trombone slide is not going to be pushed towards the beaker by a reaction force. In fact, due to real life drag, it will be pulled the other way... but if we think about a no-drag situation, the slide would just float there, would it not?

Comment: Does your model include drag forces in the horizontal pipe?  Those must be overcome and will cause a pressure gradient to arise in that pipe.

Comment: @ChetMiller But what you said was done in the tank, so there was no reaction force at the pipe outlet.

Comment: @CortAmmon I modified my drawing. The exit section refers to section A-A. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Of course there is no reaction force at the pipe outlet.  What do you think would be applying that force?

Comment: @ChetMiller You seem to be wrong. It is generally believed that there is a reaction force at the outlet of the pipe.

Comment: And what would be applying this reaction force at the outlet?   Have you ever heard of something being a "wide misconception."

Comment: @ChetMiller Don't you think there's a reaction at the outlet of the pipe? Is there any reaction force at the outlet of the nozzle of the fireman's fire pipe?

Comment: My answer to both these questions is "no" and "no."  I don't know how I can say it more plainly.  Now its your turn.  You still haven't answered my question.  If there is a reaction force at the pipe (or nozzle) exit, please identify the external body that is causing this mysterious contact force of yours.  If you decline to answer this simple question, I will not be responding to this thread any longer.

Comment: @ChetMiller Wait a minute, I'll answer your question through a diagram. I'm drawing this picture.

Comment: @ChetMiller I have given my answer, please read it.

Comment: I have submitted a quantitative Answer to the straight hose problem for your consideration.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Yes, there is a pressure gradient, but there is no reaction at the outlet section, right?

Answer (score 1):

We have a perfectly straight hose running from left to right along the x axis.  The area A of the hose cross section is constant along its length, but, in the nozzle, it tapers to $A_E$ at the nozzle exit.  We are going to be looking at a control volume of the fluid between a cross section in the constant-area portion of the hose (location 1) and the hose exit (location 2).

Applying Bernoulli's equation to the fluid in this control volume yields:
$$P_1+\rho V_1^2/2=\rho V_2^2/2$$where $$V_1=\frac{\dot{M}}{\rho A}$$and$$V_2=\frac{\dot{M}}{\rho A_E}$$with $\dot{M}$ representing the mass flow rate.  The fluid gauge pressure at the exit is zero, because it is atmospheric.

To get the horizontal force of the hose on the fluid, we need to also use a macroscopic momentum balance, which is given by:$$P_1A-F=\dot{M}(V_2-V_1)$$where the right hand side represents the rate of change of momentum of the fluid in the control volume and F represents the magnitude of the horizontal force exerted by the hose and nozzle (mainly applied within the nozzle) on the fluid in the control volume.

If we combine these two equations, and solve for the force F, we obtain $$F=\frac{\dot{M}^2(A-A_E)^2}{2\rho AA_E^2}$$This force is positive, and acts on the fluid in the direction opposite to the fluid flow.  A force balance on the section of hose and nozzle encompassing the control volume then indicates that F also represents the tension in the hose in the portion of the hose leading up to the nozzle.  So, for flow through a straight hose and nozzle, the hose is under tension.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128656/discussion-on-answer-by-chet-miller-is-this-the-paradox-of-reaction-forces).

Answer (score -1):

[image: Figure 1]
As shown in the figure, suppose we have a beaker with a hole at the bottom, and water flows out of the hole.  We all know that there is a force opposite to the direction of water flow in the cross section of the hole.  Why is there such a reaction force?  Because the water has acceleration in the cross section of the hole.

[image: Figure 2]

As shown in Figure 2, if we enlarge the hole of the beaker, we will find that the diameter of the water becomes smaller and smaller at a horizontal distance H after leaving the section of the hole.  What does this phenomenon show?  This shows that the acceleration of water continues to exist after leaving the cross section of the hole (note that this is not the acceleration of water in free fall).  Therefore, the pressure of the water in the cross section of the hole is not the atmospheric pressure, but a pressure higher than the atmospheric pressure.  This pressure is the source of the force opposite to the direction of the water flow-the reaction force.

Does the exit section of the fire nozzle also have a reaction force?  Of course there is.  Because the fire-fighting nozzle is a pipe with a gradually decreasing diameter, the diameter of the water gradually decreases after its exit section, so the pressure of the exit section of the fire-fighting nozzle must be higher than atmospheric pressure.  Therefore, there must be a reaction force at the exit section.

The garden hose expands under the pressure of water, so in the direction of the water flow, the garden hose spraying water is actually a pipe with a gradually decreasing diameter.  Therefore, according to the reaction force of the beaker and the fire nozzle, the outlet section of the garden hose also has a reaction force.

### **This is true even if the garden hose is straight.**

Some people don't understand the reason that the pressure of water outside the outlet section will still be higher than atmospheric pressure: let me give you an example. What happens when the water column ejected from two hoses meets in space? The pressure P of the interface will increase, and the higher the speed, the higher P. Note that there are no nozzles or walls that restrict water in the space at this time. The same is true for the water ejected from a nozzle. Outside the outlet section, the pressure P of the water will also be higher than the atmospheric pressure, and the higher the speed of the water, the higher the P. The reasons have been explained in the relevant preceding paragraphs.

Comment: The only reason the the flow cross section gets a little smaller after the exit is because of rearrangement of the velocity profile.  This is negligible and causes negligible reaction force.  The absolute pressure of the fluid in the stream at the exit is essentially atmospheric pressure, and this can be neglected if we are working with gauge pressures.   Your assessment in your original post was correct.  The is no reaction force at the exit, and the acceleration near the entrance to the tube is produced by a reaction force of the fluid behind it in the tank.  This ultimately is provided by

Comment: the slightly increased pressures at the back wall of the tank.  So the real reaction force is provided by the back wall of the tank.

Comment: @ChetMiller So how does the reaction force between garden hose and fire nozzle come into being?

Comment: A straight garden hose and straight fire hose and nozzle are both in tension.  They are not being pushed back.  The reaction force only comes into play when the garden hose or fire hose centerline becomes curved , as when one tries to change the direction the outlet end is pointing.  Then there is centripetal acceleration of the fluid along the curve, and you must provide this sideways force on the hose.

Comment: @ChetMiller Is there a pressure measurement on the outlet section? Besides, the acceleration of water is at the pump, not in the fire pipe, right?

Comment: I'm going to submit an analysis of a perfectly straight hose for you to consider.  Would that be OK?

Comment: @ChetMiller I welcome your analysis very much.